# overridePendingTransition on first start does not work (application start only!)

Tags: android, animation

I'm calling `overridePendingTransition` in `onCreate` and `onPause` and everything is working fine...

But when the application starts, the transition is not working...

Any tricks for getting this to work?

Comment: Did you activate animations in your cellphone setting ?

Answer (score 0):

it happen may be you are not creating new instance of your activity.
may be us set intentflage. like 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(about_intent);